# How to reuse common tests in phpspec

Tags: php, phpspec

Is there any way to reuse common tests in phpspec when using PHP 7?. In PHP 5.6 it was possible to do like this:

```
class AbstractCommonSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    public function it_should_test_something(SomeClass $some object) {}
}

class EntitySpec extends AbstractCommonSpec {
}
```

In PHP 7 such approach fails because of [this issue](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/issues/1021). Is there any other way how to reuse common tests?

Comment: Reusing code in tests is bad practice. A test must be easy to read and understand at a glance, without requiring investigation in other parts of the file or in other files.

Comment: I agree, but I have some common tests that should be executed, otherwise, I need to copy/paste the same code in around 20 tests

Comment: why is this question too broad? I asked concrete way how I can reuse common tests in phpspec.